# I've disabled Cortana, how do I reenable it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-search, cortana

I disabled Cortana a while back by changing the file name in windows apps but now I want to enable it again as I need the search bar to work again and I can't remember what I need to name the file.

If you see my Windows/SystemApps directory in the picture (below), there is one file called "Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy" and one filed that is just called "Cortana". This second one is the one I believe I changed last time. I posted an image in the comments of the contents of the two "Cortana" files.

Any ideas on what I should change it back to? Thanks a lot guys

[image: WindowsApps]

Comment: `Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy` is the correct name of the folder

Comment: You did more then just rename a folder.  What else did you do...

Comment: I can't remember it was a long time ago. Here's a screen shot of the contents of the two folders, if that helps. "Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy" on the left and "Cortana" on the right: http://imgur.com/gEypQOe